# AWS Route 53 -- create Hosted Zone with third level Domain Name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, nameservers

I would like to point my Elastic Beanstalk application to a specific domain `app.company.com`.  To do it (according to [AWS Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.Route53.html)), I have to create Route 53 Hosted Zone for this mapping. The problem is that I cannot change the name servers for the `company.com`. However, I would still like to use `app.company.com` for my Elastic Beanstalk. Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, ask those in charge of your company DNS servers to create a CNAME record pointing to your beanstalk application endpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to go onto your domain registrar and add `app.company.com` there. Then add a `CNAME` to point to the Elastic beanstalk endpoint.

You can't use Route53 without moving the nameservers to point to AWS

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For any followers to this question, have a look at this AWS article: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html

Comment: It's incorrect to say that Route53 can't be used for this use case - you can simply create a `app.company.com` domain as a hosted domain within Route53 and then have NS records for that Route53 domain delegate the `app` 3rd-level domain to Route53, on the `company.com` nameservers.